# How to split equally two mat-form-fields in a row in angular material 8?

Tags: bootstrap-4, angular-material

How to split equally  two mat-form-fields in a row in angular material 8?

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3 col-xs-12" style="width: 50%">

        <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput placeholder="Mode" readonly>
        </mat-form-field>

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3 col-xs-12" style="width: 50%">
        <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput placeholder="Type" readonly>
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `col-md-6` without `offset-md-3` (More about [offset](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#offsetting-columns)). `style="width: 50%"` is unnecessary. Note also that this will work only for viewports ≥768px ([source](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#grid-options)) and `col-xs-*` in bootstrap 4 is `col-*`.

Explanation: since each bootstrap row has 12 cells and your div needs 9 cells (6 + 3 for offset), second div is moved to the next row. Once you remove `offset-md-3` both divs are in the same row.

See the following demo: 
(I had to add `col-6 offset-3` and `col-6` because snippet output is too small for `col-md-*`)

```css
.red{
  background: red;
}

.yellow{
  background: yellow;
}

.row {
  height: 100px;
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="col-12">
Current situation:

<div class="row border">
  <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3 col-6 offset-3 red"></div>
  <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3 col-6 offset-3 yellow"></div>
</div>

Sub-divs in one row:

<div class="row border">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-6 red"></div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-6 yellow"></div>
</div>

Space between:

<div class="row border">
  <div class="col-5 red"></div>
  <div class="col-5 offset-2 yellow"></div>
</div>

Space around:

<div class="row border justify-content-around">
  <div class="col-5 red"></div>
  <div class="col-5 yellow"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: also, I need some space between two divs
could you suggest?

Comment: It depends how much space you need. `<div class="col-5"><div class="col-5 offset-2">` would propably leave too much space. You could set both divs to `col-5` and play with `margin`. Or leave `col-6` and add `padding` if space could be between divs' content, not the divs itself.

Comment: I've added examples with space. You may find helpful [horizontal alignment classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#horizontal-alignment)